# Sasapay register URL returns error 404. What could be the problem?

Tags: api, payment, mpesa

## Not Found

The requested resource was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

404 means the requested resource could not be found.

This means the provided URL is not valid or does not point to a file.

Maybe you can provide a little bit more context.

[A list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: https://sandbox.sasapay.app/api/v1/payments/register-ipn-url/ > This is the link on their documentation here https://docs.sasapay.app/docs/products/c2b/registerURL so maybe they should update it. #sasapay